# Docker container file permission changing Automatically

Tags: docker

While i tried to edit a file in docker container (in server).I cant access Because the  file have only read permission.This same file was working finely few minutes ago.I have  already logged in as root.

i have already searched in and can't find a answer.I have already created a Docker file and using this file(image) i have build a container.Please help

Thanks in advance.